# Deleting Records from a database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am creating a project that includes a like button. It's all working up until the delete record.

**long delete** returns the correct ID in the database. Here's the code. I'm obviously using the **db.Likes.Remove(delete)** the wrong way.

```
public ActionResult LikePicture(int userID, int pictureID)
    {
        Picture picture = new Picture();
        bool liked = picture.LikePicture(userID, pictureID);

        if (liked == true) //Remove Like
        {
            long delete = (from like in db.Likes
                     where userID == like.UserID && pictureID == like.PictureID
                     select like.LikeID).SingleOrDefault();


                     // Remove like from database
                     **db.Likes.Remove(delete);



        }
        else 
        {
            // Add like to database
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I was looking for a db.Likes.DeleteOnSubmit() but intelesense didn't give me the option so I tried the remove. As in all my questions I will say, I am new to C# so please keep it simple =) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't select the `ID` if you want to delete your item select your item

```
var item = (from like in db.Likes
                 where userID == like.UserID && pictureID == like.PictureID
                 select like).FirstOrDefault();
```

And you can use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid exception, then check for null and `Remove` the item:

```
if(item != null)
{
    db.Likes.Remove(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This works great! I'm always getting muddled up with when to use what in a linq query. But I guess that comes with experience